# BuiltIn Function to Convert from Hex String to Byte

Tags: c#

This question is similar to the [one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/convert-hex-string-to-byte-array).

One can easily convert from hex string to byte via the following formula:

```
    public static byte[] HexStringToBytes(string hex)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[hex.Length /2];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i+=2)
        {
            data[ j ] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
            ++j;
        }
        return data;
    }
```

But is there a built-in function ( inside .net framework) for this?

Answer (score 3):

Remove `0x` and then use `byte.Parse(textRepresentation, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)`

Comment: It only converts to `byte`, not an array of `bytes`

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing directly, cause there are so many possibilites. Eg. hex, octal, binary, with preceding `0x` or `0X`, etc.

But this *[How to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx)* should give you some more *easier* possibilities by using [System.Globalization.NumberStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx).