# Take a string to a byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

I have a string in my database that represents an image.  It looks like this:

```
0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000000F00000014008020000000D8A66040....
<truncated for brevity>
```

When I load it in from the database it comes in as a byte[].  How can I convert the string value to a byte array myself.  (I am trying to remove the db for some testing code.)

Comment: Can you provide code for "loading from database"?

Comment: It is loaded by linq-to-dataset for my app.  (The app that loads it is a Compact framework app.)  I tested the loading and saving to a file so I know that works.  I then send the byte[] over the wire and store it in a SQL Server 2008 db (via linq-to-sql).  I don't pull it out of the 2008 db yet.  The goal of this is to find an easy way to verify that the image is in the db correctly.

Comment: Thanks to all the answers.  I went with the linq version cause I like linq.  Everyone who figured I need to go from hex to byte[] got an upvote from me.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking how to convert a string with a particular encoding to a byte array.

**If so, it depends on how the string is encoded.** For example, if you have a base64 encoded string, then you could get a byte array using:

```
asBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(someString);
```

If the encoding is hexadecimal (as it appears to be in your example) there's nothing built into the BCL, but [you could use LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/convert-hex-string-to-byte-array/321404#321404) (*just remove the `0x` at the head of the string first*):

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex) { 
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length). 
        Where(x => 0 == x % 2). 
        Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.SubString(x,2), 16)). 
        ToArray(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        byte[] bytes = StringToByteArray("89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000000");
    }

    public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        int length = hex.Length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 2)
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're actually trying to convert the *hexadecimal* number to a byte array.

If so, you can do it like this: (Remove the `0x` first)

```
var bytes = new byte[str.Length / 2];
for(int i = 0; i < str.Length; i += 2)
    bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(str.Substring(i, 2), 16);
```

(Tested)

Answer (score 1):

If it comes in as a `byte[]`, then it's not a string.

What is the column data type? Varbinary?

Comment: It is varbinary[max].  But I am taking what is shown by SSMS and copying that.  (So at that point it is a string.)  I want to write an simple tool that will allow me to plug that value into the app and it will show me the image.

Comment: Then you need to parse the a hexadecimal number.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`String` in .NET means “text” – there’s a fundamental difference to a byte array and no 1:1 mapping exists (just as for other complex .NET types).

In particular, a string is *encoded* in an appropriate character encoding. As has already been posted, a given text can be decoded into a desired byte representation. In your particular case, it looks as though you’ve got a individual bytes represented as padded hexadecimal numbers, i.e. every byte is two characters wide:

```
int bytelength = (str.Length - 2) / 2;
byte[] result = new byte[byteLength]; // Take care of leading "0x"
for (int i = 0; i < byteLength; i++)
    result[i] = Convert.ToByte(str.Substring(i * 2 + 2, 2), 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

**String to Byte Array Conversion in C#**
http://www.chilkatsoft.com/faq/dotnetstrtobytes.html

Comment: I gave that a try and the conversion gave me a byte[] but it did not work when I plugged it into this: `MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);  pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(stream);`