# How to convert a String to a Hex Byte Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa, in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)

For testing my encryption algorithm I have being provided keys, plain text and their resulting cipher text.

The keys and plaintext are in strings

How do i convert it to a hex byte array??

Something like this : `E8E9EAEBEDEEEFF0F2F3F4F5F7F8F9FA`

To something like this :

```
byte[] key = new byte[16] { 0xE8, 0xE9, 0xEA, 0xEB, 0xED, 0xEE, 0xEF, 0xF0, 0xF2, 0xF3, 0xF4, 0xF5, 0xF7, 0xF8, 0xF9, 0xFA} ;
```

Thanx in advance :)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/convert-hex-string-to-byte-array

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa-in-c too. Tho there are different solutions shown there, so maybe all topics can live :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Do you need **this**?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa-in-c/311179#311179)

```
static class HexStringConverter
{
    public static byte[] ToByteArray(String HexString)
    {
        int NumberChars = HexString.Length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
        {
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(HexString.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        }
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx):

```
string hexValues = "48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 21";
string[] hexValuesSplit = hexValues.Split(' ');
foreach (String hex in hexValuesSplit)
{
    // Convert the number expressed in base-16 to an integer.
    int value = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
    // Get the character corresponding to the integral value.
    string stringValue = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(value);
    char charValue = (char)value;
    Console.WriteLine("hexadecimal value = {0}, int value = {1}, char value = {2} or {3}", hex, value, stringValue, charValue);
}
```

You only have to change it to split the string on every 2 chars instead of on spaces.

Answer (score 0):

did u mean this

```
StringBuilder Result = new StringBuilder();
    string HexAlphabet = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    foreach (byte B in Bytes)
        {
        Result.Append(HexAlphabet[(int)(B >> 4)]);
        Result.Append(HexAlphabet[(int)(B & 0xF)]);
        }

    return Result.ToString();
```