# Use Microsoft.Web.Administration to import certificate in IIS?

Tags: c#, ssl, iis

I am trying to programmatically install a certificate in IIS. The solutions I have found are similar to this: [Install SSL Certificate programatically using Microsoft.Web.Administration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083732/install-ssl-certificate-programatically-using-microsoft-web-administration). Basically it says to do something like this:

```cs
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
var certificate= new x509certificate2(certFilePath);
store.add(certificate);
```

However, this adds the certificate to the users personal certificate store. What I am trying to do is add it to IIS Server Certificates. The user would use IIS to create a certificate request, send it to a CA to get a .cer file, then my tool would take that file and complete the certificate request, storing the certificate in IIS.

Is there a way to use `Microsoft.Web.Administration` to do this?

Comment: You can find most of the features implemented in Jexus Manager already, https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/blob/master/JexusManager.Features.Certificates/CertificatesFeature.cs

Comment: Here are your duplicates: [Install SSL certificate programmatically using Microsoft.Web.Administration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5083732/608639).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install SSL certificate programmatically using Microsoft.Web.Administration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083732/install-ssl-certificate-programmatically-using-microsoft-web-administration)

Comment: Some comment on the linked question this is a duplicate of: You need to do both, first add the certificate to the Windows Certificate Store and then configure IIS to use that certificate for a certain binding. See the answer by Helephant for the second part.