# how to upload the image from iphone and using .NET webservices

Tags: c#, iphone, .net, web-services, base64

I want to upload the image using the .NET webservices and that will be called from iphone image.

the format of text that iphone is sending to me is like this.

http://d8768157.u118.c6.ixwebhosting.com/iphoneimg/image.txt

In which datatype i must convert this data and then save that in image format.

If you have any other method then please tell me.

I have tried converting this data in the byte[] but it is giving me error. here is my code. For what i have tried. please help me out.

```
[WebMethod]
    public XmlDocument testuploadimage(string image)
    {
        XmlDocument login = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDeclaration dec = login.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
        login.AppendChild(dec);
        XmlElement root = login.CreateElement("CreateUser");
        login.AppendChild(root);
        try
        {

            string actFolder = Server.MapPath("~/iphoneimg/");
            string imgname = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString().Replace(" ", "").Replace("AM", "").Replace("PM", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("-", "").Replace(":", "") + ".png";

            Bitmap map;

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(image)))
            using (FileStream fs = File.Create(actFolder + imgname))
            {
                map = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(stream);
                map.Save(fs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            }

            XmlElement root1 = login.CreateElement("uploaded");
            root1.InnerText = "true";
            root.AppendChild(root1);
            XmlElement root2 = login.CreateElement("path");
            root2.InnerText = "http://d8768157.u118.c6.ixwebhosting.com/iphoneimg/" + imgname;
            root.AppendChild(root2);

            return login;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

this is the error i m getting

**Invalid character in a Base-64 string.**

Thanks

BHAVIK GOYAL

Comment: Can you please add the error message you're getting?  Stack trace as well?

Comment: @Jonathan i have updated with error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[WebMethod]
public XmlDocument testuploadimage(string image)
{
    XmlDocument login = new XmlDocument();
    XmlDeclaration dec = login.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
    login.AppendChild(dec);
    XmlElement root = login.CreateElement("CreateUser");
    login.AppendChild(root);
    try
    {

        string actFolder = Server.MapPath("~/iphoneimg/");
        string imgname = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString().Replace(" ", "").Replace("AM", "").Replace("PM", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("-", "").Replace(":", "") + ".Png";

        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(image.Replace(" ","+"));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

        // Convert byte[] to Image
        ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        System.Drawing.Image image2 = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        image2.Save(actFolder + imgname);


        XmlElement root1 = login.CreateElement("uploaded");
        root1.InnerText = "true";
        root.AppendChild(root1);
        XmlElement root2 = login.CreateElement("path");
        root2.InnerText = "http://d8768157.u118.c6.ixwebhosting.com/iphoneimg/" + imgname;
        root.AppendChild(root2);

        return login;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

}
```

I got the answers...

thanks to all....

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is a fundamental problem with your situation.

You are passing a non-Base64 string to Convert.FromBase64String().

Looking at the link you sent, the iPhone looks like it's sending hex characters with spaces.

You options are to either have the iPhone send you Base64, or remove the spaces and convert what the iPhone is sending now.

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/convert-hex-string-to-byte-array) is a link with code
  converting Hex to byte[].
- [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is a link on what Base64
  encoding is.
- [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) is a link    describing
  hexadecimal, which is what    the
  iPhone is sending you.