# receiving multi images over tcp

Tags: c#, android

this code is receiving multi images(video) from c# server over tcp .and working fine.but it is very slow and also missing frames is their any way to make it fast(eliminate delay) like without closing socket,or instead of using data input stream.

```
    private Runnable connectSocket=new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            { 

                        try { 
                                        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 4444);
                            DataInputStream dis;
                            try { 


                                dis=new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                                int bytesRead;
                                byte[] pic = new byte[5000*1024];
                                bytesRead = dis.read(pic, 0, pic.length);
                                 bitmapimage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(pic, 0, bytesRead);              


                            } catch(Exception e) { 
                                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e); 
                            } finally { 
                                socket.close(); 
                            } 

                        } catch (UnknownHostException e) { 
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                            Log.e("TCP", "C: UnknownHostException", e); 
                            e.printStackTrace(); 
                        } catch (IOException e) { 
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                            Log.e("TCP", "C: IOException", e); 
                            e.printStackTrace(); 
                        }
                        imgview.setImageBitmap(bitmapimage);
                        imgview.invalidate();


    }
             mHandler.postDelayed(this, 0); 
        } 
    };


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending image by image is not a very good way. Consider using compressed video formats.

Also you can't really make it fast. It all depends on what network device is in 2G will always be slower than wifi / 3G.

Comment: i just dont want to reopen and reclose socket.is it posible ?