# How can I convert a string of hex to a byte[]

Tags: c#, .net

I do not want to encode a `string` to a `byte[]`. I want to turn a `string` of hex numbers to a `byte[]`. How can I do that?

Note: I again repeat I do not want to use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` or any other encoding.

A sample `string` is detailed below:

```
0x42A2C6A046057454C2D1AB2CE5A0147ACF1E728E1888367CF3218A1D513C72E582DBDC7F8C4674777CA148E4EFA0B4944BB4998F446724D4F56D96B507EAE619
```

How can I convert this `string` to a `byte[]` of the numbers in the string.

Comment: Why are the `Encoding` classes not suitable? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/net-string-to-byte-array-c

Comment: You want to transform a string to a byte array but you don't want to specify the encoding. How would you possible decode it back to a string without knowing how it was encoded?

Comment: How did you encode the data when you where writing it to your database? You will need this when reading it from the db.

Comment: So, you have a string that represents an encoded byte array, like you example and you want to convert it into a byte array?

Comment: That byte sample does not look like Unicode (to few 0x00) so I'm quite sure you do _not_ want to cast and that in fact you do need an Encoding. Maybe ASCII instead of UTF-8.

Comment: he wants the hex-string converted to the byte[] equivalent. So instead of making 0x42A string equal to the byte[] = {0x34,0x32,0x41} he wants it to be byte[] = {0x4, 0x2, 0xA} therefore he can't use the GetBytes()?

Comment: Here is a simple solution that I made: http://pastie.org/2380850

Comment: @jgauffin: Exactly what I wanted. Please post it as answer. I need to accept it. My question was unncessarily closed without understanding what I wanted to say. Thankfully it is not downvoted..fingers cross!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/convert-hex-string-to-byte-array and all the duplicates of that

Comment: That was exactly what I was thinking as well @jgauffin. (except that I took a nibble instead of the byte, my mistake), upvoted for the sake of a mistaken closing!

Comment: @Anthony, just upvote the answer of one of the preexisting questions, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/convert-hex-string-to-byte-array

Comment: People get so overly enthusiastic here. Just few misunderstandings in question and people come from nowhere and heavily downvote you or close your question.

Comment: @Anthony: While I agree with you that this is a problem, in this case, the problem is that you simply didn't state what you really wanted.

Comment: @Daniel: I didn't know how to express this. I expressed best what I knew.

Answer (score 2):

There is no unambiguous way to convert a string to a byte array, that's why you need to use the `Encoding` class. In your case, you can use `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()`, because you only have characters from the ASCII charset.