# String to byte array

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa, in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)
>   [Convert hex string to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/convert-hex-string-to-byte-array)

I've an string like this:
"021500010000146DE6D800000000000000003801030E9738"

What I need is the following byte array:
02 15 00 01 00 00 14 6D E6 D8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 38 01 03 0E 97 38 (each pair of number is the hexadecimal value in the respective byte).

Any idea about how can I make this conversion?? Thanks!!

Comment: Did you to write to do something ?

Comment: The “possible duplicate” is a completely different question. He's not asking how to encode the string into a `byte[]` using some encoding. The string here contains hexadecimal values that should be converted to `byte[]`.

Comment: I don't see how these questions are exact duplicates.

Comment: You pretty much want the second example on this page:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx.  The "meat" of it is Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16) (the second parameter specifies to convert from Base-16, which is Hex).  I found this with Google: "C# parse hex"

Comment: I've also seen the "duplicate" thread, and I really think this is completely different.

Comment: Looks like exact duplicate to me - please comment on how the linked questions are different from what you want: hex string -> byte array (and all samples so far are about the same as potential duplicate ones)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var arr = new byte[s.Length/2];
for ( var i = 0 ; i<arr.Length ; i++ )
    arr[i] = (byte)Convert.ToInt32(s.SubString(i*2,2), 16);
```

Comment: This code is really working well. But only a detail, right code is "s.Substring".

Thanks to all.

Comment: Can use Convert.ToByte instead of ToInt32.

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much want the second example on this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx).
The important part is:

```
Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
```

The first parameter is a 2-character string, specifying a hex-value (e.g. `"DE"`).
The second parameter specifies to convert from Base-16, which is Hex.

Splitting the string up into two-character segments isn't shown in the example, but is needed for your problem.  I trust its simple enough for you to handle.

I found this with **`Google: "C# parse hex"`**

Answer (score 1):

```
    string str = "021500010000146DE6D800000000000000003801030E9738";
    List<byte> myBytes = new List<byte>();

    try
    {
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            myBytes.Add(Convert.ToByte(str.Substring(0, 2), 16));
            str = str.Substring(2);
        }
    }
    catch (FormatException fe)
    {
        //handle error
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < myBytes.Count; i++)
    {
        Response.Write(myBytes[i].ToString() + "<br/>");
    }
```

Comment: `Convert.ToByte` on an `int`?  I mean, premature optimization is bad and all, but when the simplest approach is also faster...

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, I found that right function to do in one convert. Thanks!