# How to set specific variable types in config file

Tags: c#

I just added the settings config file to my C# console application and I'm looking to store a list of byte arrays, however I'm unfamiliar. Is there any way to do this so that next time I launch my app it has the same values in the arrays in the list?

Comment: Please do some research. A hint on search terms: `strongly typed configuration in C#`.

Comment: A similar question has been asked for web.config: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9787335/880990