# Convert String[] to byte[] array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, byte

I'm trying to convert this string array to byte array.

`string[] _str= { "01", "02", "03", "FF"};` to `byte[] _Byte = { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0xFF};`

I have tried the following code, but it does not work.
    `_Byte = Array.ConvertAll(_str, Byte.Parse);`

And also, it would be much better if I could convert the following code directly to the byte array :
`string s = "00 02 03 FF"` to `byte[] _Byte = { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0xFF};`

Comment: I assume all the strings describe hexadecimal numbers?

Comment: yeah, it missing on the str part :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work:

```
byte[] bytes = _str.Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();
```

using [`Convert.ToByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k.aspx), you can specify the base from which to convert, which, in your case, is 16.

If you have a string separating the values with spaces, you can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) to split it:

```
string str = "00 02 03 FF"; 
byte[] bytes = str.Split(' ').Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();
```

Comment: @AhmadHafiz cool :) Also added a solution for converting a string. You can mark my response as answer if it helped you :)

Comment: I know this thread is old but I got a problem here.

If i convert my string[] to byte[]

I get for example   [0] "70" string
  [1] "34" string
  [2] "0A" string
to   [0] 112 byte
  [1] 52 byte
  [2] 10 byte
But I need the same characters as byte.

Comment: @Noli they **are** the same. "0A" is 10 in hexadecimal notation. It's just displayed in decimal format. The value is correct.

Comment: Ohhhh that is so.... I spent hours... But thank you sooo much for this!! Thank you!

Comment: Your code struck with unable to parse... this solution worked fine.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11268578/4425004

Answer (score 4):

Try using LINQ:

```
byte[] _Byte = _str.Select(s => Byte.Parse(s)).ToArray()
```

Comment: Won't help. His problem is that `Byte.Parse` will not accept a string in hexadecimal format.

Answer (score 2):

With LINQ is the simplest way:

```
byte[] _Byte = _str.Select(s => Byte.Parse(s, 
                                           NumberStyles.HexNumber,
                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                          ).ToArray();
```

If you have a single string  `string s = "0002FF";` you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8235530/637425)

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `Array.ConvertAll` if you prefer, but you must specify base 16. So either

```
_Byte = Array.ConvertAll(_str, s => Byte.Parse(s, NumberStyles.HexNumber));
```

or

```
_Byte = Array.ConvertAll(_str, s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16));
```

Comment: Didn't know of that solution. Nice :)

Comment: Of course you can use `string[] _str = stringWithSpaces.Split(' ');` to create `_str` in the first place, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ConvertAll you could try this:

```
byte[] _Byte = Array.ConvertAll<string, byte>(
    _str, s => Byte.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var bytes = str.Select(s => Byte.Parse(s, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray();
```