# Converting a string array to a byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, byte

Ok, before anyone attempts to label this as a duplicate, I am *not* asking for a string to a byte array. I want a string array, containing something similar like this: {"5","168","188","28","29","155"} to be converted to a byte array. I have searched, and was only able to find string to byte array, which is quite different. Thanks.

Edit: the array will be preset so that each member is parsable through byte.Parse, so this is not an issue.

Comment: Please provide a more specific example.  What do you mean?

Comment: See this answer on serialization: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1446547/228080

Comment: Do you have a string array, like `new string[] {"5","168","188"}` or a string containing an array like syntax, like `"[5,168,188]"`?

Comment: Without more context - specifically of what you are trying to achieve with this transformation, we can't really help.

Comment: Are you trying to take the string literal "[5,168,188,28,29,155]" and convert it to the equivalent ` new byte[]{5,168,188,28,29,155}`?

Comment: Any requirements around the format of the output? BinaryFormatter from System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters could get the job done. Alternatively, you could convert each string to a byte array (ensure that it is null terminated) and combine those arrays, etc. Please provide some more detail so we know how to better help you.

Comment: Do you mean foreach-ing over the string array and calling Byte.Parse() on each iteration?

Comment: @Guffa The first one is what I meant, sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: You can still edit your question and clarify it.

Comment: @RyanBennett This worked for me! Thanks for saving my day.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will fail for anything that *can't* be parsed by `byte.Parse`

```
var str = new[] {"5", "168", "188", "28", "29", "155"};
var byt = str.Select(byte.Parse).ToArray();
```

Comment: worked for me, i was debugging my API response in bytes, So i logged the bytes to textpad and trying to rebuild the response bytes.

Answer (score 6):

You have to parse each string into a byte and put in a new array. You can just loop though the items and convert each one:

```
string[] strings = { "5", "168", "188", "28", "29", "155" };
byte[] bytes = new byte[strings.length];
for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++) {
  bytes[i] = Byte.Parse(strings[i]);
}
```

You can also use the [`Array.ConvertAll` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx) for this:

```
string[] strings = { "5", "168", "188", "28", "29", "155" };
byte[] bytes = Array.ConvertAll(strings, Byte.Parse);
```

You can also use LINQ extensions to do it:

```
string[] strings = { "5", "168", "188", "28", "29", "155" };
bytes = strings.Select(Byte.Parse).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean that you have a string array like `string[] myArray = {"5","168",...};`:

```
myArray.Select(x => byte.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Or:

```
myArray.Select(byte.Parse).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

**With linq**

```
string[] strings = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
byte[] byteArray = strings.Select(x =>  byte.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

**Without linq**

```
string[] strings = { "1", "2", "3", "4" };

byte[] bytArr = new byte[strings.Length];

int i = 0;

foreach(String text in strings)
{
  bytArr[i++] = byte.Parse(text);  
}
```