# Convert string[] to byte[] and back to string[] and display it

Tags: c#

```
string[] s1 = { "5", "168", "789", "28", "29", "155" };
string s2[] = {"abc","bcs"};

private byte[] byteBuffer;

public ClientState(Socket clntSock)
{
    this.clntSock = clntSock;
    rcvBuffer = new byte[BUFSIZE]; // Receive buffer

    byteBuffer = new byte[strings.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)
    {
       byteBuffer[i] = Byte.Parse(strings[i]);
    }

}

string[] strings = { "5", "168", "23", "28", "29", "155" };

private const int BUFSIZE = 32; // Size of receive buffer
private byte[] rcvBuffer;
private Socket clntSock;
private byte[][] byteBuffer;
private NetworkStream netStream;

public ClientState(Socket clntSock)
{
    this.clntSock = clntSock;
    rcvBuffer = new byte[BUFSIZE]; // Receive buffer

    byteBuffer = new byte[strings.Length][];
    byteBuffer = ToBytes(strings);

}
static byte[][] ToBytes(string[] ascii)
{
    byte[][] results = ascii.AsEnumerable().Select(x => Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x)).ToArray();
    return results;
}
public ClientState(NetworkStream netStream, byte[][] byteBuffer)
{
    this.netStream = netStream;
    this.byteBuffer = byteBuffer;

}
public NetworkStream NetStream
{
    get
    {
        return netStream;
    }
}

public byte[][] BByteBuffer
{
    set
    {
        byteBuffer = value;
    }
    get
    {
        return byteBuffer;
    }
}  

string[] strings = { "5", "168", "23", "28", "29", "155" };

private const int BUFSIZE = 32; // Size of receive buffer
private byte[] rcvBuffer;
private Socket clntSock;
private byte[][] byteBuffer;
private NetworkStream netStream;

public ClientState(Socket clntSock)
{
    this.clntSock = clntSock;
    rcvBuffer = new byte[BUFSIZE]; // Receive buffer

    byteBuffer = new byte[strings.Length][];
    byteBuffer = ToBytes(strings);
}

static byte[][] ToBytes(string[] ascii)
{
    byte[][] results = ascii.AsEnumerable().Select(x => Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x)).ToArray();
    return results;
}

public ClientState(NetworkStream netStream, byte[][] byteBuffer)
{
    this.netStream = netStream;
    this.byteBuffer = byteBuffer;
}
public NetworkStream NetStream
{
    get
    {
        return netStream;
    }
}

public byte[][] BByteBuffer
{
    set
    {
        byteBuffer = value;
    }
    get
    {
        return byteBuffer;
    }
}


public  void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    ClientState cs = (ClientState)asyncResult.AsyncState;

    try
    {
            int recvMsgSize = cs.ClntSock.EndReceive(asyncResult);

        if (recvMsgSize > 0)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} ({1}) - ReceiveCallback(): received {2} bytes",
                              Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode(),
                              Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState,
                              recvMsgSize);

            cs.ClntSock.BeginSend(cs.BByteBuffer, 0, cs.BByteBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                                  new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), cs);
        }
        else
        {
            cs.ClntSock.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(se.ErrorCode + ": " + se.Message);
        cs.ClntSock.Close();
    }
}
```

I am converting s1 string array to byte array and I send it to a client . This is a server. So at the client I want to convert the byte array back to a string array.
With Byte.Parse I am unable to convert string s2. So how do I convert s1 string array and s2 string array to byte arrays.

I want to convert the byte arrays back to strings arrays and out put the result at the client side.

it says cannot convert from byte[][] to byte[] at  `cs.ClntSock.BeginSend(cs.BByteBuffer, 0, cs.BByteBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), cs);`

Comment: Check [How can I convert String to Int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int) and [Convert int to string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081916/convert-int-to-string) and [Convert string array to int array in one line of code using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297231/convert-string-to-int-in-one-line-of-code-using-linq)

Answer (score 2):

Well what bytes you want depends on your encoding.  But it would be something like this:

```
string myString = "hello";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString);
string fromBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
Console.Write(myString == fromBytes);
```

Comment: Its an array of string not a single string

Comment: I want to convert an array of strings to an array of bytes. and convert them back to strings and display them

Comment: @vaibhav You can add any additional explanation by editing your question, so it would be easier to understand for anybody. Check [Converting a string to byte-array without using an encoding (byte-by-byte)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/converting-a-string-to-byte-array-without-using-an-encoding-byte-by-byte?rq=1)

Comment: Its not just a string to byte array. It string array to byte array string[] to byte[]

Comment: Check [Convert String array to byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531148/convert-string-to-byte-array?rq=1)

Comment: cs.ClntSock.BeginSend(cs.BByteBuffer, 0, cs.BByteBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), cs);

Comment: the above line says cannot convert from byte[][] to byte[]

Comment: @vaibhav, the question title says string[] to byte[] and back to string[], which is what Zer0 has given you.  If you have more than one (e.g. an array of strings), you'll have to do this more than once.  You can post another question about ways to do things more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] s1 = { "5", "168", "789", "28", "29", "155" };
            byte[][] s1_byte = ToBytes(s1);
            string[] s1_out = ToString(s1_byte);
            DisplayBytes(s1_byte);
            string[] s2 = { "sdf", "dsfds", "233" };
            byte[][] s2_byte = ToBytes(s2);
            DisplayBytes(s2_byte);
            string[] s2_out = ToString(s2_byte);
        }
        static byte[][] ToBytes(string[] ascii)
        {
            byte[][] results = ascii.AsEnumerable().Select(x => Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x)).ToArray();
            return results;
        }
        static void DisplayBytes(byte[][] bytes)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.LongLength; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", new List<byte>(bytes[i]).Select(x => "0x" + x.ToString("x2")).ToArray()));
            }
        }
        static string[] ToString(byte[][] bytes)
        {
            List<string> results = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.LongLength; i++)
            {
                string newString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes[i]);
                results.Add(newString);
            }
            return results.ToArray();

        }
```

Comment: @vaibhav - "more problems in my code" Can you elaborate?