# Convert from string array to byte array

Tags: c#

I'm using C#.

I have a string array as follow: `"1,2,3,4,5,..."`
I'm trying to convert the string array to byte array as follow `[]{1,2,3,4,5,...}`
What is the best way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763613/convert-comma-separated-string-of-ints-to-int-array

Comment: Your answer lies in a previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531148/convert-string-to-byte-array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using *Linq*:

```
 string source = "1,2,3,4,5";

 byte[] result = source
   .Split(',')
   .Select(item => byte.Parse(item))
   .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
byte[] byteArray = str.Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();
```

Str represent string[]. If you have string you should string[] str = string.Split(',');

Comment: This doesn't compile because the _base_ argument is only applicable when the first argument is a string.  In your code, `s` is type `char`.  I get the following error:  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.IFormatProvider'  In addition, this will include the commas as arguments.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Str is string array the question is string array to byte array.

Comment: I re-read the question and though the OP used the words "string array", I believe they actually had a `string` and not a real `string[]` to begin with.  The accepted answer seems to support this assumption.  I agree that your answer is valid given that `str` is really a `string[]`.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I edit it, I'm from mobile so I have limited possibilities for formatting.

Answer (score 2):

```
byte[] result = Array.ConvertAll(str.Split(','), Convert.ToByte);
```