# Best way to convert file containing ASCII representations of bytes to real bytes C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I have a file containing some data (for example, "00927E2B112DB958......"). This data is a representation of bytes in ASCII form. The bytes are 8 bit, so 2 ASCII chars map to each byte that needs to go into the final output buffer array.

What is the best way to do this?

EDIT: What I am trying to do is go from a string that looks like "00DFFF" to a byte array of {0x00, 0xDF, 0xFF}, for example. I guess this wasn't clear.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/convert-hex-string-to-byte-array

Comment: it's an ASCII representation of Hex that must be converted to real bytes in an array.

Comment: Please either define in what way conversions should be "best" (pretty code, the shortes code, least memory, fastest,...) or remove "best" from the title (and avoid in the future).

Comment: I meant "least cumbersome/clunky"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private ICollection<byte> HexString2Ascii(string hexString)
{
    var bytes = new List<byte>(hexString.Length / 2);
    for (int i = 0; i <= hexString.Length - 2; i += 2)
        bytes.Add(byte.Parse(hexString.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I am trying to do is go from an ASCII input to a byte array output.

Comment: Oh ok, that should be a simple modification.

Comment: I've made the modification.  If you always want an array, make it `return bytes.ToArray();` and change the return type of the method.