# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject throws an exception when attempting to deserialize byte[] to IEnumerable<byte>

Tags: c#, json.net

The code below fails in deserialization with the following error.

Error converting value "AQID" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Byte]'

```
public class ByteArrayTest
{
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<byte> ByteArray { get; set; } 
} 

using Newtonsoft.Json;

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest10
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestTheByteArraySerialization()
    {
        var test = new ByteArrayTest { ByteArray = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }, SomeString = "testing" };
        var serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
        //This line belows fails with an error of can't convert to IEnumerable<byte>
        var myByeArrayClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ByteArrayTest>(serializedData);
        Assert.AreEqual(test.ByteArray, myByeArrayClass.ByteArray);

    }
}
```

In my particular case I don't own the ByteArrayTest class, this is just a quick example of the issue.  I'd like a solution that doesn't involve modifying the ByteArrayTest class.  Ideally I'd pass something into one of the DeserializeObject<> overloads to get this to work, but I'm unsure of the best approach to resolve this exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't expect JsonConvert to magically create an implementation for an interface.

You could use `List<byte>` or `byte[]` instead of `IEnumerable<byte>` if your architecture permits OR you can add a field to interface the Json serializer and hide your actual IEnumerable from it.

```
private IEnumberable<byte> myBytes = null;

[JsonProperty("BytesArray")]
public string JsonBytes{
get{
  return String.Join("",myBytes.Select(b=>b.ToString("X2"))); // this may need tweaking, null checks etc
}
set{
  byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
  myBytes = bytes;
} 

[JsonIgnore]
public IEnumerable<byte> BytesArray{
  get{ return myBytes;}
  set{ myBytes = value;}
}
```

You could probably provide a converter to achieve the same thing but I'd say it's too much fiddling around without the need to.

For a list of several implementations on the `StringToByteArray` see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/convert-hex-string-to-byte-array), I copied the shortest implementation.

Comment: I'm somewhat unclear what you mean by add a field interface to the Json.  To be slightly more specific I'm calling a web service and receiving this "{\"SomeString\":\"testing\",\"ByteArray\":\"AQID\"}".  So I'm not in control of the serialization.

Comment: ... I just noticed you're not deserializing HEX but something else, most likely Base64, updated answer.