# issue in converting hexadecimal to byte array

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

i have string like

```
string test = "0x527AE53437CAED39D3E2A8B3E90FFC3BA9073B6D933BC05FF6677B5521DC34"
```

How can i convert the string to byte[]?

Comment: What do you mean "to hexadecimal"? It already looks like it is. Do you mean you want to convert it to a `byte[]` array? Or to a single huuuuuuuuge integer number?

Comment: the hexadecimal number you posted is too **large**, I'm afraid that the largest integral number (`long`) can't hold it.

Comment: Note that your title says "issue" but there is no problem show in your post. You are probably missed sample code that does not behave the way you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use  `SoapHexBinary` in namespace `System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001`

```
string s = "0x527AE53437CAED39D3E2A8B3E90FFC3BA9073B6D933BC05FF6677B5521DC34";
byte[] num = SoapHexBinary.Parse(s.Substring(2)).Value;
```

Comment: Thanks 
I4V the above code worked well ......

Answer (score 0):

That string is hexadecimal.

If you want to convert it to a numeric you're going to need special handling - that's a very big number and will overflow the basic types.

If it was a reasonable size, all numeric types are agnostic of base-representation. To see a hexadecimal version of a number, you simply call `.ToString("X")` on it.

**EDIT**

My answer was based on the initial version of the question before the byte[] was specified. There is a previous SO question and answer for this: [How can I convert a hex string to a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/convert-hex-string-to-byte-array)

Comment: this will convert each `hex digit` into the corresponding `byte`, however it's just a `nibble`, we need 2 `nibbles` to convert to a `byte`.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I'll retract.