# C# help required to Create Facebook AppSecret_Proof HMACSHA256

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, hmac

Facebook requires that I create a appsecret_proof:   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests

And I have done this using the following code:

```
public string FaceBookSecret(string content, string key)
{
        var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(key);
        byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(content);
        using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
        {
            byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
        }
}
```

Everything looks fine for me, however facebook says that the appsecret_proof is invalid.   I am logged in, I can do everything as normal when i remove the key. So to save some time:

- Yes I am posting to the correct URL
- Yes I am passing a valid access_token
- Yes I am using the same access_token in the proof, as i am in the request
- Yes my appsecret is fine, and works

Example in usage

```
dynamic results = client.Post("/" + model.PostAsId + "/feed", new { message = model.Message, appsecret_proof = FaceBookSecret(postAs.AuthToken, AppSecret) });
```

I think it probably has something to do with encoding or something along them lines, but to be honest, I just dont know.

I am also using the Facebook .net SDK    however this does not have much in documentation, and does not seem to strike on anything to do with automation, server side operations etc.

Thanks

Comment: can you show more code please - how do you create `client`? Are you sure you are using same app.Id for both hash and request? Also - try `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` just in case - may be that will do the trick...

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it for facebook APIs v2.4 here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932675/how-to-send-appsecret-proof-using-facebook-c-sharp-sdk/31933544#31933544

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app secret is a base-16 string, so you need to convert that to a byte array. Take a look at [How can I convert a hex string to a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/convert-hex-string-to-byte-array) for details on how to do this. The access_token needs to be converted to a byte array using the ASCII encoding. Once you've generated the HMAC then encode this as a base-16 string to use as your appsecret_proof. The following code will convert a byte array to base16.

```
public static class Base16
{
    private static readonly char[] encoding;

    static Base16()
    {
        encoding = new char[16]
        {
            '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
            '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'
        };
    }

    public static string Encode(byte[] data)
    {
        char[] text = new char[data.Length * 2];

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            text[j++] = encoding[data[i] >> 4];
            text[j++] = encoding[data[i] & 0xf];
        }

        return new string(text);
    }
}
```

The code to generate the appsecret_proof would then be

```
private string GenerateAppSecretProof(string accessToken, string appSecret)
{
    byte[] key = Base16.Decode(appSecret);
    byte[] hash;
    using (HMAC hmacAlg = new HMACSHA1(key))
    {
        hash = hmacAlg.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(accessToken));
    }
    return Base16.Encode(hash);
}
```

Facebook seems to accept either a `SHA256 HMAC` or `SHA1 HMAC`.

Comment: This answer is missing the Base16.Decode implementation. Are we supposed to figure this out for our selves? It amazes me that this one is the accepted answer instead of the one given by Eric Kassan which is complete, correct and it works without a lot of hussle.

Comment: I didn’t include the code for Base16.Decode because there are many solutions to this already in the question I linked to (and the associated duplicate).

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/convert-hex-string-to-byte-array

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa

Eric Kassan solution is interesting in its own right because he just used UTF8.GetBytes to decode the appSecret. This would imply Facebook validates the appsecret_proof with multiple variations of the algorithm.

Answer (score 21):

I have used the below successfully with Facebook

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

internal static string FaceBookSecret(string content, string key)
{
    byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
    byte[] hash;
    using (HMACSHA256 hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes))
    {
        hash = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
    }

    StringBuilder sbHash = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
    {
        sbHash.Append(hash[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
    return sbHash.ToString();
}
```

Comment: For future users, note that the lowercase "x2" is important or you will get a 400 bad request error.