# "Specified value has invalid Control characters" when converting SHA512 output to string

Tags: c#, hash

I am attempting to create an Hash for an API.
my input is something like this:

FBN|Web|3QTC0001|RS1|260214133217|000000131127897656

And my expected output is like :

17361DU87HT56F0O9967E34FDFFDFG7UO334665324308667FDGJKD66F9888766DFKKJJR466634HH6566734JHJH34766734NMBBN463499876554234343432456

I tried the bellow but I keep getting 
"Specified value has invalid Control characters. Parameter name: value"

I am actually doing this in a REST service.

```
public static string GetHash(string text)
{
    string hash = "";
    SHA512 alg = SHA512.Create();
    byte[] result = alg.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
    hash = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);        
    return hash;
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result)` as the data in `result` is *invalid* UTF-8 (it's just binary goo!) so trying to convert it to text is invalid - in general, and specifically for this input - which results in the Exception being thrown.

Instead, convert the `byte[]` to the *hex representation* of said byte sequence; *don't* treat it as UTF-8 encoded text.

See the questions [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa) and [How can I convert a hex string to a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/convert-hex-string-to-byte-array?lq=1), which discuss several different methods of achieving this task.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make this work you need to convert the individual `byte` elements into a hex representation

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var b in result) {
  builder.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);
}
return builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using Base64 encoding (AKA UUEncode):

```
public static string GetHash(string text)
{
    SHA512 alg = SHA512.Create();
    byte[] result = alg.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
    return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
}
```

For your example string, the result is

```
OJgzW5JdC1IMdVfC0dH98J8tIIlbUgkNtZLmOZsjg9H0wRmwd02tT0Bh/uTOw/Zs+sgaImQD3hh0MlzVbqWXZg==
```

It has an advantage of being more compact than encoding each byte into two characters: three bytes takes four characters with Base64 encoding or six characters the other way.