# Using String of Bytes in a Byte Array

Tags: c#

In C# I am trying to use a string that is already in bytes to array of bytes, I can't use Linq since I am using 2.0 framework. I just want to use the string as a byte array, so converting it.

Would like to do:

```
string MYBytes ="{ 0x4D, 0x5A, 0x90 }";
byte[] getBytes = MYBytes;
```

Comment: So that should be converted to a byte array (containing 0x4D, 0x5A, 0x90)?

Comment: Where are you getting the string from?

Comment: I and downloading it the string from a webrequest.

Comment: Strings are composed of Unicode characters, not bytes.  [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes I know that it is Unicode but I would like to use the string as bytes, should I split the string and try to cover each to byte and make it to an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to split up the string and parse each item individually as a byte. Here is one way to do it:

**Update**

Looks like I pasted in the wrong fiddle link. Here is the code with he correct link.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        string MYBytes = "{ 0x4D, 0x5A, 0x90 }";

        string[] hexParts = MYBytes.Split(new char[] { ',', '{', '}' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[hexParts.Length];

        for(int i = 0; i < hexParts.Length; i++)
            bytes[i] = Byte.Parse(hexParts[i].Substring(3), NumberStyles.HexNumber);


        foreach(byte b in bytes)
            Console.WriteLine("{0:X2}", b);
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/gRMEOM

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work => `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("4d5a90", 0, resultArray, 0)`

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsy6z64h(v=vs.110).aspx

See also [How can I convert a hex string to a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/convert-hex-string-to-byte-array)

Or use unsafe code

To get a byte

`unsafe { fixed(char* s = someString) { byte b = s[0]; }}`

To get a fixed amount of bytes

`unsafe { fixed(char* s = someString) fixed(byte * bz = (byte*) s) fixed byte[3] b = bz; }`

I think you can skip the fixing to byte * too

`unsafe { fixed(char* s = someString) fixed byte[3] b = (byte *)s; }`

Comment: This is converting the text to bytes, I do not want to convert the actual value of the string to a byte I just want to use the sting's value as the byte value.

Comment: Well you have a fundamental problem... Try unsafe code...