# AES Encryption KEY conversion from python key to C#

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, rijndaelmanaged

I have a file encrypted with AES in python and its key is defined in code as:

```
key = '\x14\x15\xa2\xf6\xb6\x17\x4a\x58\xb6\x17\x4a\x58\xb6\x17\x4a\x58'
#print binascii.hexlify(key)
aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
```

However my C# code takes key parameter as something like "skey = 1234512345678976"

```
private static void EncryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile, string skey)
        {
            try
            {
                using (RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    byte[] key = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(skey);
                    ....
                }
            }
         }
```

So, how can I decrypt these files according to the same key? What is the equivalent of python key in C#? I am using C# code lies in here: http://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/encrypt-and-decrypt-files-in-c/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to do **ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(skey)**, you need to treat the key as if it was a hex string and convert it as such.  See:

[How can I convert a hex string to a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/convert-hex-string-to-byte-array)