# Compare T-SQL timestamp to c# Base64String

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, timestamp, base64

Is there some way to get Base64String from timestamp?
For example:

```
0x000000005E683A8A -> AAAAAF5oOoo=
```

I need it to debug my project.
Or how can I save timestamp value in C# without Convert.ToBase64String in this view:

```
0x000000005E683A8A
```

And then will send it to sql again?

Comment: Is your question how to convert to and from base64 in C# or in T-SQL? That is documented on the web.

Comment: No, I can convert timestamp to and from base64 when I get it from sql as array of bytes. But for example I got one of timestamps from query and saved it as Base64String in my code. Then for testing I need to change this value from another query which I run by myself in management studio. And I can't do it because I can't convert tsql timestamp to base64string by myself. Changing query and running code with a new query is not so useful.

Comment: Why can't you convert the timestamp to base64? You stated that you know how to convert between bytes and base64.

Comment: I'm bad in explanation maybe =)
This answer is useful for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/how-can-i-convert-a-hex-string-to-a-byte-array