# TAI64N to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, hex

I have a number of files that are named in TAI64N format [here is a reference](http://cr.yp.to/libtai/tai64.html). When I try using this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/321404/6724308) it comes out negative with the assist of `BitConverter.ToInt64`

```
static void Main ( string[] args ) {
    string[] filenames = new string[4]{
        "4000000057b23bf30017a4bc",
        "4000000057b23ef61dedacac",
        "4000000057b24b1c2bab0614",
        "4000000057b24ca521a230fc"
    };
    foreach (string filename in filenames) {
        byte[] hexToBytes = StringToByteArray(filename);
        long bytesToLong = BitConverter.ToInt64(hexToBytes, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(bytesToLong); // Negative?
        DateTime longToDateTime = new DateTime(bytesToLong);
    }
}

public static byte[] StringToByteArray ( string hex ) {
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
        .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
        .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
        .ToArray();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the difference between [endiannes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your TAI64N value and your processor? I assume that you are using x86-64 processor, which is little endian, while the TAI64N value is big-endian. Methods of `BitConverter` class use processor endianness to convert values ([see Remarks section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)).

I suggest you try reversing the order of bytes in array:

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray ( string hex ) {
    byte[] arr = Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
        .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
        .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
        .ToArray();
    Array.Reverse(arr);
    return arr;
}
```

And subsequently `long bytesToLong = BitConverter.ToInt64(hexToBytes, 4);`

By the way, I've noticed is that you use `new DateTime(long ticks)` constructor ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk(v=vs.110).aspx)), but you supply it with *seconds* (according to **TAI64N** specification) instead of *ticks*.