# Convert Decrypt function from Coldfusion to .NET with RC4/Hex

Tags: .net, encryption, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion page that decrypts some data from another application. The ColdFusion code is pretty simple:

```
decrypt(theString,encryptKey,algorithmType,encodeType)
```

The algorithm type is RC4 and the encode type is hex.  For whatever reason I'm having quite a bit of trouble getting this to work in .net.  Are there any resources available for this kind of thing, or is there a fairly straightforward answer?

**Update:**

I've started by using an RC4 class found here: [RC4 Encryption in C#](https://bitlush.com/blog/rc4-encryption-in-c-sharp). Although I've changed the encoding to Ascii, the results still are not matching.

```
public static class RC4
{
   public static string Encrypt(string key, string data)
   {
      Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;

      return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(unicode.GetBytes(key), unicode.GetBytes(data)));
   }

   public static string Decrypt(string key, string data)
   {
      Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;

      return unicode.GetString(Encrypt(unicode.GetBytes(key), Convert.FromBase64String(data)));
   }

   public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] data)
   {
      return EncryptOutput(key, data).ToArray();
   }

   public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] key, byte[] data)
   {
      return EncryptOutput(key, data).ToArray();
   }

   private static byte[] EncryptInitalize(byte[] key)
   {
      byte[] s = Enumerable.Range(0, 256)
        .Select(i => (byte)i)
        .ToArray();

      for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 256; i++)
      {
         j = (j + key[i % key.Length] + s[i]) & 255;

         Swap(s, i, j);
      }

      return s;
   }

   private static IEnumerable<byte> EncryptOutput(byte[] key, IEnumerable<byte> data)
   {
      byte[] s = EncryptInitalize(key);

      int i = 0;
      int j = 0;

      return data.Select((b) =>
      {
         i = (i + 1) & 255;
         j = (j + s[i]) & 255;

         Swap(s, i, j);

         return (byte)(b ^ s[(s[i] + s[j]) & 255]);
      });
   }

   private static void Swap(byte[] s, int i, int j)
   {
      byte c = s[i];

      s[i] = s[j];
      s[j] = c;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problems you are having?

Comment: What have you tried? It does not look like that algorithm is part of the core libraries, but a quick search turned up a few custom implementations .. assuming you need to maintain RC4 for backward compatibility reasons?

Comment: Oddly, RC4 exists o the CF documentation for Encrypt, but not Decrypt.  I'm not sure why that would be.

Comment: That is just a documentation error. It is valid for both.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

If the "encodeType" is actually base64 (not hex), then it is even simpler. Modify the Encrypt() function encode the result as base64. Then change the Decrypt() function to decode both values *from* base64.

```
public static string Encrypt(string base64Key, string plainText)
{

    return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(base64Key), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText)));
}

public static string Decrypt(string base64Key, string base64Encrypted)
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(base64Key), Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encrypted)));
}
```

---

> I've changed the encoding to Ascii.

Close, but that still will not decode the input correctly. So the class will ultimately try and encrypt/decrypt the wrong binary, causing it to fail. To fully replicate the CF functions you need understand how they decode the parameters:

- [Encrypt(text, key , "RC4", "hex")](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encrypt.html) - Treats `text` as a UTF-8 encoded string and `key` as base64 encoded string.
- [Decrypt(encryptedText, key , "RC4", "hex")](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encrypt.html) - Treats `text` as a *hexadecimal* encoded string and `key` as base64 encoded string.

You need to modify the C# class to do the same thing.

1. Start by creating helper functions that [convert a byte[] to hex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/311179/104223) AND [convert  hex to a byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/321404/104223):

   ```
   public static string ByteArrayToHex(byte[] ba)
   {
       string hex = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
       return hex.Replace("-", "");
   }

   public static byte[] HexToByteArray(string hex)
   {
       return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                        .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                        .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                        .ToArray();
   }
   ```
2. Modify the Decrypt() function to decode the key as base64 and the encrypted text as hex. Finally, return the decrypted value as a UTF-8 string.

   ```
   public static string Decrypt(string base64Key, string hexValue)
   {
       return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(base64Key), HexToByteArray(hexValue)));
   }
   ```
3. Modify the Encrypt function to decode the key as base64 and the plain text as UTF-8. Then return the encrypted value as hex.

   ```
   public static string Encrypt(string base64Key, string plainText)
   {

       return ByteArrayToHex(Encrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(base64Key), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText)));
   }
   ```

With those small changes, the C# code will produce the same result as the CF functions.

**NB: I would recommend reading up on [known issues with RC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Security) and consider switching to a more secure algorithm like AES.**

Comment: Almost perfect.  To make this work, I removed the hex subs and replaced them with Base64, like this, from the decrypt function:  return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(base64Key), Convert.FromBase64String(hexValue)));  Then it worked perfectly.  Thank you!!!

Comment: Ah, okay. The question description said the decrypt function was receiving a hex string, ie "*...the encode type is hex*. However, as you figured out - the binary is what matters, not the encoding. As long as both sides decode/encode the values correctly, it does not really make a difference what you use (base64, hex, etcetera).