# Send text as binary data from socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a device emulator which accept the data as text from socket.Below code works fine until I send from `0x00 to 0x7F` means upto Ascii limit (0 to 127).
Issue arise when I try to send beyond the Ascii limit like 0x80,0x81. It send to emulator 0x3F('?') and it change the whole meaning of command. because it does not able to understand this.

So What may be the possible solution to send the data beyond Ascii limit

Send data code:

```
 //string data = textBox1.Text;
 string d1 = ConvertHex("35");  //getting exact byte in socket             
 byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(d1);
 clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
 clientStream.Flush();
```

ConverHex function:

```
public static string ConvertHex(String hexString)
    {
        try
        {
            string ascii = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
            {
                String hs = string.Empty;

                hs = hexString.Substring(i, 2);
                uint decval = System.Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16);
                char character = System.Convert.ToChar(decval);
                ascii += character;

            }

            return ascii;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: are you sure that hex code is right?

Comment: Yes, I have seen the data in device emulator, Which is given by the client.

Answer (score 3):

> but when I send more than `79` then I get `3F` in emulator.

`7F` is in fact the upper bound. Because that's `127` in decimal, the highest code point supported by the ASCII encoding. Code points higher than that get decoded to a question mark, having the code point of `63` or `3F` in hexadecimal.

That's because you're using text to transmit binary data. Don't do that. See [How can I convert a hex string to a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/how-can-i-convert-a-hex-string-to-a-byte-array) for a proper implementation of "hex string to byte array".

Comment: yes, you are right. Actually device emulator which is given by client, works like that.So I can not change the emulator behavior right now. I can change only my code.