# How can I convert a git hash to a byte array with length 20 in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, data-conversion, git-hash

How can I convert a git hash to a byte array with length 20 in C#?
At the moment I represent the git hash as a string:

```
string gitHash = "0x29932f3915935d773dc8d52c292cadd81c81071d";
```

I have tried this:

```
byte[] gitHashBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(gitHash);
Array.Resize(ref gitHashBytes, 20);
```

But I actually want to convert the hex number to the byte array and not the string representation of it.

I need this to save the git hash in a smart contract where I am using bytes20 as data structure.

Why does the way I tried it above not work and just cut off the the hash after 20 digits? And what's the difference to the conversion in the proposed answer here:
[How can I convert a hex string to a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/how-can-i-convert-a-hex-string-to-a-byte-array)

Comment: Does your string really start with `0x`? That's not the normal representation of git hashes, and it slightly complicates matters here.

Comment: No, you are right. I can leave the 0x out. This was in there because I have copied it from a web3.js project.