# How do i convert hexadecimal that is stored in string and split it by , and store it in a byte array

Tags: c#, string, byte

I have the following string:

```
string hi = "0xfc,0xe8,0x82,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x60,0x89,0xe5,0x31,0xc0,0x64,0x8b,0x50,0x30,
0x8b,0x52,0x0c,0x8b,0x52,0x14,0x8b,0x72,0x28,0x0f,0xb7,0x4a,0x26,0x31,0xff,
0xac,0x3c,0x61,0x7c,0x02,0x2c,0x20,0xc1,0xcf,0x0d,0x01,0xc7,0xe2,0xf2,0x52,
0x57,0x8b,0x52,0x10,0x8b,0x4a,0x3c,0x8b,0x4c,0x11,0x78,0xe3,0x48,0x01,0xd1,
0x51,0x8b,0x59,0x20,0x01,0xd3,0x8b"
```

And I split it on the `','` character into an array:

```
string[] string1 = decrypted.Split(',');
```

Now I need a way to store `string1` into a `byte` array so it looks like:

```
byte[] byte1 = {0xfc,0xe8,0x82,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x60,0x89,0xe5,0x31,0xc0,0x64,0x8b,0x50,0x30,
0x8b,0x52,0x0c,0x8b,0x52,0x14,0x8b,0x72,0x28,0x0f,0xb7,0x4a,0x26,0x31,0xff,
0xac,0x3c,0x61,0x7c,0x02,0x2c,0x20,0xc1,0xcf,0x0d,0x01,0xc7,0xe2,0xf2,0x52,
0x57,0x8b,0x52,0x10,0x8b,0x4a,0x3c,0x8b,0x4c,0x11,0x78,0xe3,0x48,0x01,0xd1,
0x51,0x8b,0x59,0x20,0x01,0xd3,0x8b}
```

Comment: So you've taken a string (`hi`) and converted it into a string array (`string1`), but now you want to convert each element of the string array to a byte? What have you tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/how-can-i-convert-a-hex-string-to-a-byte-array You can take a reference from this above asked question.

Comment: It depends on the encoding and if it is little/bit endian.  You can use :             string myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byte1);
            byte[] byte2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString);

Answer (score 4):

You can convert a single string from hex to binary using [Convert.ToByte(string, int)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k(v=vs.110).aspx) by passing `16` as the second parameter.

With this knowledge, and a little trimming and substringing, we can convert to an array of bytes with a little LINQ:

```
var byteArray = input
    .Split(',')
    .Select
    ( 
        s => Convert.ToByte
        (
            s.Trim().Substring(2),
            16
        ) 
    )
    .ToArray();
```

[Example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uiqjmk)

Comment: plus 1 for LINQ usage

Answer (score 0):

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex) {
return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                 .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                 .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                 .ToArray();
```

}

follow the same you will get your answer

Comment: This would only work with a stream of continuous digits. OP's string contains other things too.