# How to compute a HMAC SHA256 in c#

Tags: c#, hmac

Edit: I've fixed the ascii encoding as pointed out by @DavidG

I'm creating an integration towards a vendor and the integration requires me to sign the message with a HMAC-SHA256 algorithm.

The simple test I've got from the vendor is that we're going to use this data:

```
key: "1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF" (hex)
data: "00000000" (ascii)
expected output (only first 32 chars): FF365893D899291C3BF505FB3175E880 (hex)
```

I've checked a number of online hmac generators and found them to return different results for me, some correct and some incorrect.

```
Correct reply: https://www.liavaag.org/English/SHA-Generator/HMAC/ 
Correct reply: https://cryptii.com/pipes/hmac
Incorrect reply: https://codebeautify.org/hmac-generator
Incorrect reply: http://billatnapier.com/security01.aspx
```

Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction here? This is causing me to become bald very soon...

```
    [TestClass()]
    public class AutogiroConcentFileWriterTests
    {
        [TestMethod()]
        public void ManualKVVTest()
        {
            String key = "1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF";
            String message = "00000000";
            String expected = "FF365893D899291C3BF505FB3175E880";

            Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
            Byte[] key_bytes = this.KeyData(key);

            Byte[] message_bytes = ascii.GetBytes(message);

            System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 hmacSHA256 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(key_bytes);
            Byte[] hash = hmacSHA256.ComputeHash(message_bytes);
            String data = this.ByteToString(hash);

            // only compare first 32 chars of the hash
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, data.Substring(0, 32));

            //Assert.AreEqual failed. 
            //Expected:<FF365893D899291C3BF505FB3175E880>. 
            //Actual:<997BBD8C79F0D98FCA6470723CDB65D3>.
        }

        private Byte[] KeyData(String key)
        {
            if (key.Length % 2 == 1)
                throw new Exception("The binary key cannot have an odd number of digits");

            byte[] arr = new byte[key.Length >> 1];

            Int32 pos = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < key.Length; i += 2)
            {
                Int32 b1 = key[i] - (key[i] < 58 ? 48 : 55);
                Int32 b2 = key[i + 1] - (key[i + 1] < 58 ? 48 : 55);
                arr[pos++] = (byte)((b1 << 4) + b2);
            }

            return arr;
        }

        private String ByteToString(Byte[] buff)
        {
            Char[] retval = new char[buff.Length * 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < buff.Length; i++)
            {
                String t = buff[i].ToString("X2");
                retval[i * 2] = t[0];
                retval[i * 2 + 1] = t[1];
            }
            return new String(retval);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @DavidG: It's stated by the vendor as the correct reply.

Comment: Oh, I figured out what you are doing, will write an answer.

Comment: Encoding.ASCII is no hex encoder

Comment: If you want to use HMAC-SHA256, don’t do `new HMACSHA1()`.

Comment: @Mormegil I'm guessing that's a typo, the original post did it right.

Comment: Yes, you are right that I messed that one up. I tested and forgot to change back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting your key directly to bytes rather than interpreting it as a hex string. Using a string-to-bytes function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/321404/1663001):

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                     .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                     .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                     .ToArray();
}
```

Change your code to this:

```
Byte[] key_bytes = StringToByteArray(key);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @DavidG. 
However the result of the testcase is still wrong. :(
Assert.AreEqual failed.
Expected:<FF365893D899291C3BF505FB3175E880>. 
Actual:<997BBD8C79F0D98FCA6470723CDB65D3>.

Comment: You've switched to using the wrong function, change your code back to use `HMACSHA256`.

Comment: Thanks DavidG! Somewhere down the line my frustration took over and I just went berserk on my code. When changing it back to HMACSHA256 it works. :) Thank you for your help in finding my annoying mistake!