# Convert OpenSSL encryption into native C#

Tags: c#, openssl, des

I have a legacy application which uses OpenSSL to encrypt a string using `DES3`.

These are the parameters that are set for OpenSSL:

```
OpenSSL enc -des3 -nosalt -a -A -iv 1234567890123456 -K 1234567890123456...48
```

The key is a **string** of **48 digits** and the iv is a substring of the first **16 digits** of this key.

Now, I am trying to replicate this functionality with C#'s `System.Cryptography` library and without the use of OpenSSL if possible.

My goal is not to have to use OpenSSL and have the encryption done in native C# code.

Here is what I have got so far:

```
public string Encrypt(string toEncrypt, bool useHashing)
{
    var _key = "48...digits...";
    byte[] keyArray;
    var toEncryptArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);

    if (useHashing)
    {
        var hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_key));

        hashmd5.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        keyArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_key);
    }

    var tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

    tdes.Key = keyArray;

    // Is this even the correct cipher mode?
    tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

    // Should the PaddingMode be None?
    tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    // THIS is the line where I am currently stuck on:
    tdes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_key.Substring(0, 16));

    var cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();

    var resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
}
```

As written as comments in the code, I am not quite sure if I am using the correct cipher, maybe even the padding mode is incorrect and my iv has a length of `16 bytes` but only `8 bytes` are expected.

Also, I did try my luck already with or without hashing the key/iv.

Is it even possible to convert the above mentioned OpenSSL logic into plain C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key and IV must be specified for [`openssl enc`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/enc.html) with `-K` and `-iv` as *hexadecimal* values. This is missing in the C# code, so that essentially the following expressions

```
tdes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_key);
tdes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_key.Substring(0, 16));
```

would have to be replaced by

```
tdes.Key = StringToByteArray(_key);
tdes.IV = StringToByteArray(_key.Substring(0, 16));
```

to produce the same ciphertext for `useHashing == false`. Here `StringToByteArray` is a method that converts a hexadecimal string into the corresponding byte array, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/321404/9014097).

It should also be noted that .NET does not accept keys that are too [weak](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.isweakkey?view=netcore-3.0#remarks), e.g.:

```
123456789012345612345678901234561234567890123456
```

In case of such a key a `CryptographicException` is thrown (*Specified key is a known weak key for 'TripleDES' and cannot be used*). OpenSSL accepts this key.

Regarding security:

- MD5 shouldn't be used nowadays to generate a key, more [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/62833).
- In addition, MD5 generates a 16 byte hash. Thus, always keying option 2 is used, which is weaker than keying option 1 ([Keying options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options)).
- Generally it's insecure to use the key as IV, more [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/16162).
- TripleDES is slow compared to today's standard AES, more [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/26181).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @Topaco. I also appreciate the pointers regarding security. Some of which are unfortunately not changeable by my part of the application... :-(