# How can I transform UTF-8 in form of string to string

Tags: c#, utf-8

I have this UTF-8

> 0x50 0x6C 0x61 0x6E 0x74 0x09 0x20 0x3A 0x20 0x54 0x45 0x53 0x54 0x31 0x0A 0x47 0x72 0x6F 0x75 0x70 0x09 0x20 0x3A 0x20 0x54 0x45 0x53 0x54 0x32 0x0A 0x50 0x61 0x6E 0x65 0x6C 0x20 0x54 0x6F 0x67 0x20 0x4E 0x75 0x6D 0x62 0x65 0x72 0x20 0x3A 0x20 0x54 0x45 0x53 0x54 0x33 0x0A 0x43 0x6F 0x6F 0x72 0x64 0x69 0x6E 0x61 0x74 0x69 0x6F 0x6E 0x09 0x20 0x3A 0x20 0x54 0x45 0x53 0x54 0x34

but it's a string not byte I cant use

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str2);
string str3 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

because it's a string not UTF-8 at first

Comment: You will need to convert [hex string to bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/321370/1997232) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1), [`byte.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.byte.parse?view=netcore-3.1) or [`Convert.ToByte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobyte?view=netcore-3.1#System_Convert_ToByte_System_String_System_Int32_), [`Encoding.UTF8.GetString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=netcore-3.1)

```
var input = "0x50 0x6C 0x61 0x6E 0x74 0x09 0x20 0x3A 0x20 0x54 0x45 0x53 0x54 0x31 0x0A 0x47 0x72 0x6F 0x75 0x70 0x09 0x20 0x3A 0x20 0x54 0x45 0x53 0x54 0x32 0x0A 0x50 0x61 0x6E 0x65 0x6C 0x20 0x54 0x6F 0x67 0x20 0x4E 0x75 0x6D 0x62 0x65 0x72 0x20 0x3A 0x20 0x54 0x45 0x53 0x54 0x33 0x0A 0x43 0x6F 0x6F 0x72 0x64 0x69 0x6E 0x61 0x74 0x69 0x6F 0x6E 0x09 0x20 0x3A 0x20 0x54 0x45 0x53 0x54 0x34";

var bytes = input
   .Split(' ')
   .Select(x => byte.Parse(x.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber))
   .ToArray();

// or

var bytes = input
   .Split(' ')
   .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x, 16))
   .ToArray();


Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes));
```

**Output**

```
Plant    : TEST1
Group    : TEST2
Panel Tog Number : TEST3
Coordination     : TEST4
```