# Cannot decrypt OPEN-SSL AES 128 ECB encrypted string using C# - The input data is not a complete block

Tags: c#, encryption, openssl, aes

After using current Open SSL command (decrypt content from file "encrypted.msg"):

```bash
openssl enc -d -aes-128-ecb -in "C:\encrypted.msg" -out "c:\temp\decrypted.msg" -K "e2fc714c4727ee9395f324cd2e7f331f" -nopad
```

I get a new file where the decrypted content is the same as the original.

If a try to decrypt the same encrypted file content from C# (NET 7)
I always get an exception: ... `The input data is not a complete block.` ...

This is my decrypt Code

```
 private static string GetHASH(byte[] RawBytes, HashAlgorithm AlgoritmoDiHASH)
 {
     if (RawBytes is not { LongLength: > 0 }) return "";
     var bytes = AlgoritmoDiHASH.ComputeHash(RawBytes);
     var builder = new StringBuilder();
     foreach (var t in bytes)
     {
         builder.Append(t.ToString("x2"));
     }

     return builder.ToString();
 }

public static string GetMd5(string rawData)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawData))
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    return GetHASH(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawData), MD5.Create());
}

  public static byte[] AESByteArrayDecryption(byte[] encryptedBytes, string key, CipherMode cipherMode = CipherMode.CBC, PaddingMode paddingMode = PaddingMode.PKCS7, int blockSize = 128, int keySize = 256)
  {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
      {
        throw new Exception("Chiave di decrittazione non valida");
      }

      if (encryptedBytes.LongLength == 0)
      {
         throw new Exception("Dati da decrittografare non validi");
      }

      var keyB = new byte[32];
      var tmp = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
      Buffer.BlockCopy(tmp, 0, keyB, 0, Math.Min(tmp.Length, 32));

using (var rm = Aes.Create())
{
    rm.BlockSize = blockSize;
    rm.KeySize = keySize;
    rm.Mode = cipherMode;
    rm.Padding = paddingMode;

    using (var dencryptor = rm.CreateDecryptor(keyB, (cipherMode != CipherMode.ECB ? new byte[blockSize / 8] : null)))
    {
        using (var dencryptStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedBytes))
        {
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(dencryptStream, dencryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                var decryptBytes = new byte[encryptedBytes.Length];
                cryptoStream.Read(decryptBytes, 0, decryptBytes.Length);
                return decryptBytes;
            }
        }
    }
}
  }

 var cipherMode = CipherMode.ECB;
 var paddingMode = PaddingMode.None;
 var blockSize = 128;
 var keySize = 256;
 var pwdMD5 = CryptographyUtil.GetMd5("abcd");
 
   var decriptedData = CryptographyUtil.AESByteArrayDecryption(criptedData, pwdMD5, cipherMode, paddingMode, blockSize, keySize);
   var decriptedDataString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decriptedData);
```

String to derive MD5 = "abcd"

### Encrypted File

```
j›}2}0‹ÂN_’-#€6µC÷úð+|™wyh”–Ú`WŽ µÄîôZÌ¢Cü‘Êœœ4zw=-á¶(ör»”qÛ‰ ÀðMl}Ï„%ðŸ9]Ë° $„üÌR†E)zÆÝ‚¦”J4-¸–éÇ  æ&þ`:¯ê—ç‹ß<+K/´ö#Ë‘’Âé·_NFò‚øCUk³`ÚÂ¾µh-ïQõ£®®èá}R±}å,M\™û‡Í°öÃ§/–ÌàOÙ”ÒšßN¥þÀP
ø'†èì—Nh
#Ä›á•ÆöjÈ¦JæËãJ’^_«.ÂK¯‚ýR*ËdîdtÍB¶ÆpçZÑŸ·oM°Ž7I}ŠÏáˆjS½Ð4Æ=ßÙ¿ré(»²”=[ˆÿjÐ¹„cÕ.W®ºïI±PB/úuÓŸic¸D®_¾c£3D‰Èwë‚áJì&ÛÂÙû}Cùô
—ÆÀËl¬~Ð§Ô²ÈyÇÎ±    ÈÆhbSê¾ ç»ûg¢çð²POêA–Á“üïbV|Ë "Æ‘G&éýù>üÂ µr ÒÅ/Í)®8XU›M}1E2ÚÀúaâ³’d¾¦Ý»TV‘°ŠÖÀñÁa  ¤×}:*ØÎ¯ßLÿklÌÐÄàæ4úN››w—ÊÑ ù=Pzf›ÿ%J µµ¾Nf‚{eÔleÊs‹ðý…©m¤¸ò¬†0Ñü*D‰ÀøÖˆ’…RòÒ‰013¾QYó   ,&Ñ»§<»J{«»"©‡ÆÐñ,¦®â…òž~ËkAž<êˆ˜]8i8ÿ0ãÚÔFÙ™ö\®ŠM—zOÓ¶·è”Y
```

### Plain File Content

```xml
<reading version="2"><cam><name>Test-Road</name><serial>682719AE6F5E</serial><mac></mac></cam><date>2024-01-19T09:14:06.230Z</date><timestamp>1705655646230</timestamp><plate><adr><kemler>33</kemler><onu>1203</onu></adr><value>ABCDE123</value><direction>-1</direction><country>ITA</country><vehicle>truck</vehicle><speed>20</speed><x>1419</x><y>387</y><width>197</width><height>46</height></plate><images><ocr><url>http://localhost:7572/img/2024/01/19/10/2024-01-19-10-14-06-FG050EE_full.jpg</url></ocr><context><url>http://localhost:7572/img/2024/01/19/10/2024-01-19-10-14-06-FG050EE_ctx.jpg</url></context></images></reading>
```

Comment: The most likely issue is that the contents of `encryptedBytes` (`criptedData`) are not precisely (byte-for-byte) the contents of `encrypted.msg`. If I had to guess at the difference, the first thing I'd verify is that there isn't an extra newline at the end of `criptedData`.

Comment: The error message is probably caused by a (somehow) corrupted ciphertext (s. previous comment). But apart from that, OpenSSL statement and C# code are different with regard to key size (OpenSSL: AES-128, C#: AES-256) and key derivation (OpenSSL: none, C#: via MD5). Incidentally, ECB does not use IV (you can pass `null`). Post a complete code (`CryptographyUtil.GetMd5()` is missing) and (short) sample data.

Comment: Regarding AES-ECB itself, read this: [**Why shouldn't I use ECB encryption?**](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20941/why-shouldnt-i-use-ecb-encryption)  It's OK for learning and experimenting, but its secure uses are limited.

Comment: I try to remove IV (var decryptor = rm.CreateDecryptor(keyB, null);) but I have same issue

Comment: @Andrew Henle: The encrypted data comes from third parties and I have no control over it

Comment: You may not decode a ciphertext with a charset encoding, as you seem to have done. This will generally corrupt it. You must either make the file available so that it can be downloaded, or encode the contents of the file with a binary-to-text encoding and make it available (e.g. by loading the file with a hex editor and posting the hex encoded contents).

Comment: You are still using the wrong key: You hex encode the MD5 hash, UTF-8 encode the result and use that as key, which is wrong. Use directly as key: `MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abcd"))`. BTW, MD5 is a broken digest and thus a vulnerability.

Comment: Your "cripted file" output above is not the actual data in that file. It's most likely a Latin-1 decoding of the data, which is extremely lossy (~12.5% of the characters are unprintable and so are lost). You need to look at the actual bytes of the file, not a string decoding of it. If you are performing string encoding or decoding, that could be the cause of this particular error message as well.

Comment: Now, after get bytes directly from real encripted file i get a new Exception.
Source: System.Security.Cryptography
Exception Message: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.

Comment: Post the ciphertext as described (either as file download or the hex or Base64 encoded content). However, this error message is strange if you are really using `PaddingMode.None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found and resolved my problem changing this below lines of my postal code, related to get password bytes value:

```
 var keyB = new byte[32];
 var tmp = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
 Buffer.BlockCopy(tmp, 0, keyB, 0, Math.Min(tmp.Length, 32));
```

With

```
var keyB = StringToByteArrayFastest(key);

private static byte[] StringToByteArrayFastest(string hex)
{
   if (hex.Length % 2 == 1)
     throw new Exception("The binary key cannot have an odd number of  digits");

   byte[] arr = new byte[hex.Length >> 1];

   for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length >> 1; ++i)
   {
     arr[i] = (byte)((GetHexVal(hex[i << 1]) << 4) + (GetHexVal(hex[(i << 1) + 1])));
   }

   return arr;
}

private static int GetHexVal(char hex)
{
    int val = (int)hex;
    //For uppercase A-F letters:
    //return val - (val < 58 ? 48 : 55);
    //For lowercase a-f letters:
    //return val - (val < 58 ? 48 : 87);
    //Or the two combined, but a bit slower:
    return val - (val < 58 ? 48 : (val < 97 ? 55 : 87));
}
```

I found the two new method mentioned above on this post:
[Decrypting AES in C# where the file was encryped using OpenSSL -nosalt; the AES is expecting a size 16 byte array IV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65745182/decrypting-aes-in-c-sharp-where-the-file-was-encryped-using-openssl-nosalt-the/65947296#65947296)