# Hex value to Base64 is not in correct format VB.net

Tags: vb.net, base64, hex

I am trying to convert string to hex then to Base64, it is working but but base64value getting is not matching - Vs 2008(.net 3.5) & vs 2019 (.net 4.6)

this my code
--HEX string

```
Dim QrCodeHex as string ="010c426f6273205265636f726473020f3331303132323339333530303030330314323032322d30342d32355431353a33303a30305a0407313030302e303005063135302e3030"
dim QrCodeBase64En as string = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(QrCodeHex))
```

I am getting this result- is wrong

> MDEwYzQyNmY2MjczMjA1MjY1NjM2ZjcyNjQ3MzAyMGYzMzMxMzAzMTMyMzIzMzM5MzMzNTMwMzAzMDMwMzMwMzE0MzIzMDMyMzIyZDMwMzQyZDMyMzU1NDMxMzUzYTMzMzAzYTMwMzA1YTA0MDczMTMwMzAzMDJlMzAzMDA1MDYzMTM1MzAyZTMwMzA=

Correct Result is

> AQxCb2JzIFJlY29yZHMCDzMxMDEyMjM5MzUwMDAwMwMUMjAyMi0wNC0yNVQxNTozMDowMFoEBzEwMDAuMDAFBjE1MC4wMA==

how do i get it.

Comment: The first base64 string contains the hex-string. The second (the correct one)  contains the underlying string. `Bobs Records3101223935000032022-04-25T15:30:00Z1000.00150.00` but you wrote that you are *trying to convert string to hex then to Base64*, but the step to convert to hex seems not to be necessary. Just convert the orignal string to base64 instead.

Comment: we need the following details to base64.

Comment: we need the following details to base64. Tag + Length + value.  Tag is 1 , Length is 12 & data is "Bobs Records" .  bas64 string to hex conversion should be  010c426f6273205265636f726473.  eg 112Bobs Records   to base64 and decoding base 64 to hex 010c426f6273205265636f726473. please help

Comment: thanks - its working now

Answer (score 4):

`System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` converts a (regular) string to a byte array. However, in your case, you don't have a regular string ("Bobs Records...") but a hexadecimal representation of the byte array ("010c426f62..."). So you need to convert that hex representation to a byte array first:

```
Dim QrCodeHex As String = "010c426f6273205265636f726473020f3331303132323339333530303030330314323032322d30342d32355431353a33303a30305a0407313030302e303005063135302e3030"
    
' Hex to bytes
Dim bytes As Byte() = BigInteger.
    Parse(QrCodeHex, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier).
    ToByteArray().Reverse().ToArray()
    
Dim QrCodeBase64En As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)
    
Console.WriteLine(QrCodeBase64En)
```

([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yJg3Th))

Note: I just used BigInteger for conversion, since it was the most compact way to do so without relying on .NET 5+ features. (The `Reverse` is required because, by default, it outputs the number as little-endian.) See this question for alternatives: [How can I convert a hex string to a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/321370/87698)

Comment: thanks -- it working now

Comment: Dear @heinzi I'm also having the same problem. i'm working on JAVA-11 platform. Could you please help me.

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;
public class QrCodeSample {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Charset cset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
  byte[] bArr = "010c426f6273205265636f726473020F3331303132323339333530303030330314323032322d30342d32355431353a33303a30305a0407313030302e303005063135302e3030".getBytes(cset);
  String bVal = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bArr);
  System.out.println(bVal);
 }
}

Comment: @mahmoodsk: Sure, here is how to do the conversion from string to byte array in Java: https://stackoverflow.com/q/140131/87698