# Hex input to SHA256 hash

Tags: c#, hex, sha256

online hash code can be obtained from this site with SHA256.

https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html

The hash code of 1 is "6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b"

but if we make the hash code input type of 1 hex, "4bf5122f344554c53bde2ebb8cd2b7e3d1600ad631c385a5d7cce23c7785459a" comes out.

I can do the first one in c# code, but I couldn't find a c# code that can do the second one. Could you help?

```
    static string ComputeSha256Hash(string rawData)
    {
        // Create a SHA256   
        using (SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create())
        {
            // ComputeHash - returns byte array  
            byte[] bytes = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawData));

            // Convert byte array to a string   
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                builder.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: *I can do the first one in c# code* --- paste that working code and i'll try to rewrite to 2nd one.

Comment: I updated the question and added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this, the key is [convert hex to bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/321404/1518100).

```cs
        public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
        {
            int len = hex.Length;
            //the stackoverflow answer assumes you have even length,
            //so I insert a 0 if odd length.
            if (len % 2 == 1)
            {
                hex = hex.Insert(0, "0");
            }
            return Enumerable.Range(0, len)
                             .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                             .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                             .ToArray();
        }

        static string ComputeSha256Hash(string rawData)
        {
            using (SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create())
            {
                byte[] bytes = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(StringToByteArray(rawData));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
                {
                    builder.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
                }
                return builder.ToString();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string hash = ComputeSha256Hash("1");
            Console.WriteLine(hash);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: I did not understand your code. What should I do to get the hash value of 1.

Comment: updated with full code.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks

Comment: System.FormatException: Additional non-parsable characters are at the end of the string.